# Web application deployed on Tomcat and Forward Proxying

Tags: tomcat7, http-proxy

I have a web app that makes outbound internet connections/requests, like sending an email.
I want the requests to go to a forward proxy, so the forward proxy enforces rules and such.

I'm assuming Tomcat needs to be configured to make this happen?
Looking to get started researching how to do this.